# Join set with multiple keys

Tags: lua, redis

Please advise me, if there is a better solution.
I have single set with ID, and multiple keys with values, for instance:

```
items
---
121
122
123
```

and keys for each set entry:

```
keys
---
item:121 value1
item:122 value2
...
item:123 valueN
```

What I need to do, is to join set items with values by key into result list. 
I can do this using the lua script and for statement.

Or, there is more fancy solution, maybe its better to use single `HSET` instead of separate keys to store indexed values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions is difficult to understand. Below is one way of interpreting it. Feel free to correct it in order to clarify your question:

```
 items = {
     "121",
     "122",
     "123"
 }

 keys = {
     ["item:121"]: "value1",
     ["item:122"]: "value2",
     ["item:123"]: "value3"
 }

 -- correlate the two tables
 result = {}
 for i,item in pairs(items) do
     result[item] = keys["item:" .. item]
 end

 -- result:
 result = {
     ["121"] = "value1",
     ["122"] = "value2",
     ["123"] = "value3"
 }
```

Comment: yes. that's is the exact answer on my question. Thank you.